# Updating table fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

There is an odoo system with a timesheet module (self-made) in it. 
How it works: worker came — time of the arrival has written in the timesheet — everything's good.
But there is a problem: employees, responsible for making such records, are using different timing formats: some of them are using standart HH:MM (e.g. 10:30) and some of them are using tenths HH:T (e.g. 10.5, which means the same 10:30 or even 10.125 (10:08)), so I had to make a convertation function.

Job's done, it works, but I bet there is a way to optimize it. At least, the last part of it.

```
@api.one
def time_button (self):
    def ftohhmm(a):
       if a:
          a = re.sub(',' , '.' , a)
          if (re.search ('^\-?\d+((,|\.)\d+)?$',a) >= 0): 
             if float(a) <24: 
                a = float(a) * 60
                minutes = a%60
                hours = a/60
                if int(round(minutes)) < 10:
                   return str(int(hours))+":0"+str(int(round(minutes)))
                else:
                   return str(int(hours))+":"+str(int(round(minutes)))
       return a
    if self.format:
       for i in self.ids_string:
          i.hours1=ftohhmm(i.hours1)
          i.hours2=ftohhmm(i.hours2)
          i.hours3=ftohhmm(i.hours3)
          i.hours4=ftohhmm(i.hours4)
          i.hours5=ftohhmm(i.hours5)
          i.hours6=ftohhmm(i.hours6)
          i.hours7=ftohhmm(i.hours7)
          i.hours8=ftohhmm(i.hours8)
          i.hours9=ftohhmm(i.hours9)
          i.hours10=ftohhmm(i.hours10)
          i.hours11=ftohhmm(i.hours11)
          i.hours12=ftohhmm(i.hours12)
          i.hours13=ftohhmm(i.hours13)
          i.hours14=ftohhmm(i.hours14)
          i.hours15=ftohhmm(i.hours15)
          i.hours16=ftohhmm(i.hours16)
          i.hours17=ftohhmm(i.hours17)
          i.hours18=ftohhmm(i.hours18)
          i.hours19=ftohhmm(i.hours19)
          i.hours20=ftohhmm(i.hours20)
          i.hours21=ftohhmm(i.hours21)
          i.hours22=ftohhmm(i.hours22)
          i.hours23=ftohhmm(i.hours23)
          i.hours24=ftohhmm(i.hours24)
          i.hours25=ftohhmm(i.hours25)
          i.hours26=ftohhmm(i.hours26)
          i.hours27=ftohhmm(i.hours27)
          i.hours28=ftohhmm(i.hours28)
          i.hours29=ftohhmm(i.hours29)
          i.hours30=ftohhmm(i.hours30)
          i.hours31=ftohhmm(i.hours31)
```

Hours1-31 are the columns for every day. Rows are for workers. Cells at the intersections contain exact time when worker came.

Any advise of how to optimize it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please reedit your code by removing the wired `<------>`.

Comment: Yup, noticed that right after it was posted. Done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in self.ids_string:
    for j in range(1, 32):
        if hasattr(i, "hours%s" % j):
            a = getattr(i, "hours%s" % j)
            setattr(i, "hours%s" %j, ftohhmm(a))
```

maybe this answer is your need.

Comment: Thanks, that one fits perfectly.
Also, I've got another suggestion in my another thread, tried it and seemingly it works as well. Gonna post it here so someone may find it useful someday.


`for j in range(1, 32):

    hours = 'hours{0}'.format(j)

    setattr(i, hours, ftohhmm(getattr(i, hours)))`

Comment: if 31 is a day,  you have to be sure what  day  is existed.Some month has not 31 day.

Comment: Well, it's just a calendar-based timesheet, so I'd say the only threat is when employees adding time to the wrong cell (day off or holiday) and  I hope they aren't that reckless, but.. It's could be better to restrict it anyways. Thanks for the idea.